# IMDbDataAccessError: IMDbPy and Cinemagoer no longer work

Tags: imdb, imdbpy

I've been working with IMDbPy on and off for the last year. For a week now, all of my codes have stopped working and even the simple codes from tutorials don't work. I always get the same error message:

> IMDbDataAccessError: {'errcode': None, 'errmsg': 'None', 'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/find?q=matrix&s=tt', 'proxy': '', 'exception type': 'IOError', 'original exception': <HTTPError 308: 'Permanent Redirect'>}

I tried it alternatively with Cinemagoer and get the same error message there too.

Has anyone an idea of ​​the reasons why?

Comment: Cinemagoer is currently broken. Try this library instead (not affiliated): https://pypi.org/project/PyMovieDb/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a more detailed tutorial for PyMovieDb? I can't figure out how to get the filmography on a person.

Comment: Not that I know of. The GitHub page has the same examples. I think your best option is to post an issue there and see if the maintainers reply.

Comment: last version works

Answer (score 0):

update to the latest version of cinemagoer with the following command resolved my issue.

```
pip install cinemagoer --upgrade
```