# HTTP 403 and 308 status code in Python3.10 Web Scratch

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to scrape a website for homework, with firstly a **Error 403 Forbidden** returned, the code is:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
request = Request(url)

response = urlopen(request)
```

The run results:

[image]

Then I add a header with **'User-Agent'**:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"
request = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

response = urlopen(request)
```

But It returns **Error 308**:

[image]

could you help me?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75351392/imdbdataaccesserror-imdbpy-and-cinemagoer-no-longer-work) there seems to exists libraries that do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this link: `https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/`

instead of `https://www.imdb.com/chart/top`.

If you enter the url without the last `/` on your browser, you will be redirected to the link you should use.